# Is it possible to have nested ko.utils.arrayFilter?

Tags: knockout.js

Below is my json.

```
  [
  {
    heading: "name1",
    viewable: true,
    items: [
      {
        name: "name2",
        status: true
      },
      {
        name: "name1-2",
        status: false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    heading: "name2",
    viewable: false,
    items: [

    ]
  },
  {
    heading: "name3",
    viewable: true,
    items: [
      {
        name: "name3-1",
        status: true
      },

    ]
  },
  {
    heading: "name4",
    viewable: true,
    items: [

    ]
  }
]
```

I am converting this JSON into an observable array, I want to filter this array by name present in nested array items (). I tried using nested ko.utils.arrayFilter but its not giving me any output. It always give me an empty array.

What is the best way to filter the array by nested array element?

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a test you can call in your filter. Something like:

```
function nameInList(name, list) {
  var result = false;

  ko.utils.arrayForEach(list, function(item) {
    if (item.name === name) {
      result = true;
    }
  });

  return result;
}
```

Then your filter could look like

```
ko.utils.arrayFilter(myList, function (item) {
  return nameInList('name2', item.items);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, is there a way where i can get parent array always however child array items() should be filtered based on condition?

Comment: Of course. Start with an empty array named `result`. Use `arrayForEach` to go through the parent array, use `arrayForEach` to go through the child array, and test the items. If the test is true, push the item onto the `result` array.

Comment: I did this today morning!! my problem is i only want books which user searched for listed under parent array not all.

Comment: It may be time to ask a new question.